# Typescript React/Nextjs styled-components - passing function as prop to component throws error on missing type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I'm new to typescript and struggling with a typescript error while passing down the function "toggle" as a prop to the styled-component "MobileIcon".
I have set the function type for "toggle" in the interface IProps and added it to the styled-component.

**Layout.tsx:**

```
import { FunctionComponent as FC, ReactNode, useState } from "react";
import Toolbar from "src/components/Toolbar";

interface IProps {
  main: ReactNode;
}

const Layout: FC<IProps> = ({ main }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    console.log("toggle ok");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Toolbar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
      </nav>
      <main>{main}</main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

**Toolbar.tsx:**

```
import { FunctionComponent as FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Link from "next/link";

// Components
import Brand from "./Brand";

interface IProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  toggle: () => void;
}

const Toolbar: FC<IProps> = ({ isOpen, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>
          <Brand />
        </a>
      </Link>
      <MobileIcon isOpen={isOpen} onClick={toggle}>...</MobileIcon>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Toolbar;
```

**styled-component:**

```
const MobileIcon = styled.div<IProps>`
...
`
```

**Error:**

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & IProps, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Property 'toggle' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; isOpen: boolean; onClick: () => void; }' but required in type 'Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; } & IProps, never> & Partial<...>, "theme">'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, IProps, never, "div", "div">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, IProps, never, "div", "div">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
    Property 'toggle' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; isOpen: boolean; onClick: () => void; }' but required in type 'Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; } & IProps, never> & Partial<...>, "theme">'.
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Post the IProps interface that's in scope with MobileIcon, I have a feeling that you called it onClick

Answer (score 0):

On your JSX, you use your MobileIcon as this:

> ```
>   <MobileIcon isOpen={isOpen} onClick={toggle}>...</MobileIcon>
> ```

So the props of MobileIcon here are isOpen and onClick. You don't have a toggle prop.

Your MobileIcon props interface is then:

```js
interface MobileIconProps = {
   isOpen: boolean;
   onClick: () => void;
}
```

And can be used as:

```js
const MobileIcon = styled.div<MobileIconProps>
```

Comment: you saved my day. :)
it works after changing it.

For my understanding: I thought onClick is a normal method on the component MobileIcon. Is this different with typescript. Normally in React I can pass the prop down to the method directly.

Comment: The only thing that changes is that we need the type of the props. For native HTML elements, typescript has types for those props, but with custom components/third party ones you have to define the props by yourself/import the types from the type definitions of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IProps` specifies a `toggle` prop. Therefore your `MobileIcon` component also expects that prop, yet you don't specify it in your `Toolbar` component.

Perhaps you didn't want your `MobileIcon` to use the props specified by `IProps`, but just `{}` (no props) instead. After all, a `div` doesn't have `isOpen` or `toggle`.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin for the fast reply.

The "isOpen" prop is for styling/animating the styled-component MobileIcon and the toggle is for the function call while clicking on the component = hamburger menu icons